# Managing file system objects using JavaScript console (JSC) on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, command-line-interface, filesystemobject

What is alternative for ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") in javascript CLI (jsc) for Mac OS?

I need to enumerate files and folder, created/delete, read and write content of files

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax calls. You can use jQuery library with `jQuery.load()` method call.